# DESAFIO: algoritmo de atualização de movimento retilíneo uniformemente variado visando a inércia num determinado ponto final

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, jogos, engine, física

> ## Pergunta

Quero um algoritmo que atualize (de um instante para outro, com certo intervalo de tempo entre os dois) um movimento uniformemente variado visando um valor final fazendo o movimento mais rápido possível, que recebe:

- um `CurrentValue = valor atual` (o valor pode ser uma posição, um ângulo, um score, uma variável qualquer)
- uma `CurrentSpeed = velocidade atual` (pode ser velocidade de deslocamento, de rotação, de ganho de pontuação, de mudança de valor de uma variável qualquer)
- uma `Acceleration = magnitude de aceleração` (positiva)
- um `FinalValue = valor final` a ser alcançado entrando em inércia no instante final (quando para em cima da posição final)
- um intervalo `DeltaTime` passado a partir da circunstância atual, em que se tem valor `CurrentValue` e velocidade `CurrentSpeed`

tudo isso configurando uma curva e uma circunstância de movimento retilíneo uniformemente variado e o algoritmo, finalmente, retorna

- um `NewCurrentValue = novo valor atual depois do intervalo DeltaTime`
- uma `NewCurrentSpeed = nova velocidade atual depois do intervalo DeltaTime`

levando em conta que a cada instante a aceleração em movimento é uma de três possíveis:

- `-Acceleration` quando desacelerar leva ao instante final mais rapidamente do que acelerar (quando está perto do fim)
- `+Acceleration` quando acelerar leva ao instante final mais rapidamente do que desacelerar (quando está longe do fim)
- zero nos instantes a partir do final (que são os de inércia na posição final, aí a aceleração zero conserva a inércia).

Preferivelmente, com exatidão matemática, possibilitando se for um caso possível que até se alcance o ponto final em uma só chamada de função. Erros somente de cálculo em processador.

Pergunta complicada de entender?
Para ficar mais claro, vou contextualizar o problema.

> ## Contexto

É muito comum, por exemplo, em desenvolvimento de jogos digitais se usar a função `lerp` (linear interpolation) para mudanças uniformes de valores dos mais diversos onde o argumento é, na maioria das vezes, proporcional a uma quantidade de tempo. Envolve até mesmo mudanças de posições nas físicas implementadas nas engines.

```
lerp( arg , val0 , val1 ) = val0 + arg*( val1-val0 )
```

Com o argumento partindo de `arg=0` e chegando a `arg=1`, linearmente o retorno parte de `val0` e chega a `val1`.

Se determinarmos um movimento retilíneo uniforme com
- `ti` = tempo inicial
- `vi` = valor inicial
- `tf` = tempo final
- `vf` = valor final
- `t` = tempo atual

podemos obter não só a velocidade constante `(vf-vi)/(tf-ti)` mas também o valor atual pela fórmula `lerp( (t-ti)/(tf-ti) ,  vi , vf )`.

Portanto `lerp` serve até para calcular ao longo do tempo o estado atual de movimentos uniformes se tiver esses dados, mas não uniformemente variados. O `lerp` aplica polinômio linear, já posição em movimento uniformemente variado envolve polinômio quadrático. Sendo assim, outro meio é necessário.

Além disso, se no movimento uniforme ao invés de ter
- `ti` = tempo inicial
- `vi` = valor inicial
- `tf` = tempo final
- `vf` = valor final
- `t` = tempo atual

tivesse
- `v` = valor atual
- `s` = velocidade constante
- `dt` = intervalo de tempo a partir do momento atual

estaríamos numa situação muito comum onde se sabe valor e velocidade atuais bem como o tempo que vai passar num intervalo, mas não sabemos as condições de partida e o momento em que o movimento termina.

Ainda assim, para atualizar as condições durante o intervalo podemos calcular o novo valor atual usando simplesmente a fórmula `v+s*dt` e, sabendo também `vf` (valor final), podemos saber se cruzou o valor final ou mesmo calcular quanto tempo falta para alcançar o valor final usando a fórmula `(vf-v)/s`.

Com isso, fica claro que podemos atualizar um movimento retilíneo uniforme ou qualquer outra coisa matematicamente similar, tanto contabilizando o tempo atual quanto não o fazendo mas sim utilizando o estado atual para calcular o próximo. O problema é que se bruscamente o movimento é cessado ao alcançar o valor final não se observa uma suavidade de movimento.

É por isso que deseja-se um meio de fazer isso simulando movimento retilíneo uniformemente variado, preferencialmente por uso de dados de estado atual (valor e velocidade, que são os que continuamente mudam ao longo do movimento).

Para isso, é necessário que se alcance o ponto final parando, entrando em inércia e, ainda por cima, a aceleração deve ser selecionada de modo que se alcance o instante final o mais rápido possível, acelerando quando está distante e desacelerando no momento que isso fizer parar exatamente no ponto final (e, ao estar no ponto final parado, a aceleração é zero).

Sendo assim, o que se deseja é um algoritmo que utiliza nos cálculos o valor atual, a velocidade atual, o tempo até o próximo instante, o valor final buscado e a magnitude da aceleração (porque a aceleração em si pode ser positiva ou negativa de acordo com o estado -- e ainda considera-se que a aceleração pode ser zero) para encontrar o valor e a velocidade no próximo instante.

Note que o mais interessante é que se for implementado simplesmente como uma função que recebe essas entradas, identifica a situação e gera as saídas, isso faz com que a cada atualização se possa perseguir o valor final, mesmo que a cada chamada ele mude, sempre com fluência de movimento, sem paradas bruscas.

Comment: Quantas dimensões devo levar em consideração? Em tese 2 já bastaria para ilustrar tudo, mas pode ser feita a mesma matemática para n dimensões, sem tirar nem por nada.

Comment: A propósito, a aceleração dada será um vetor? Ou ela sempre aponta "para baixo"?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que se considerar a aceleração como vetor não implicará em maiores dificuldades na solução, então não vejo motivos para não generalizar.

Comment: Desculpe, eu sumi mas voltei. A pergunta foi feita de forma genérica, dizendo que pode expressar não apenas deslocamento mas qualquer coisa. Falando em dimensões, eu pensei em uma só, mas aceito abstrações que tratam a variável como vetor de n dimensões, n=1,2,3,... e que as fórmulas utilizem os padrões matemáticos ou físicos de forma abstraída, como preferir.

Comment: Ainda assim, por mais que eu aceite fórmulas genéricas onde "valor" é vetor de n dimensões, velocidade é um "valor" por unidade de tempo e aceleração um "valor" por unidade ao quadrado de tempo (e módulo positivo), ainda assim eu fiz uma pergunta pensando em uma única dimensão para facilitar, pois são muitas as formas de tratar a necessidade de fazer curvas e acredito que com o algoritmo em uma dimensão dá para tratar múltiplas dimensões de diversas maneiras.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como eu descobri uma maneira de fazer isso, vou postar como resposta à minha própria pergunta. Ainda assim, estou aberto a mais respostas. Inclusive vou utilizar uma abordagem de uma dimensão e caso se encontre soluções adequadas a múltiplas dimensões eu as olharei com prazer e possivelmente dou o acerto para uma resposta diferente da minha.

Só lembrando que em múltiplas dimensões podem ter curvas, ou seja, o vetor de velocidade pode apontar ou não para o ponto final e assim requerer uma mudança de ângulo. Sabemos que pode-se utilizar uma abordagem onde o vetor velocidade só aponta para o ponto final (o que pode causar curvas de ângulos muito grandes e destruir a suavidade visada) e essa abordagem é fácil de se implementar com base na solução de uma dimensão, portanto não tenho interesse nessa. Outra abordagem é a de trabalhar com um ângulo variável que muda ao longo do movimento com suavidade, inserindo nas fórmulas de alguma maneira.

Agora vamos à solução abordando uma única dimensão.

> ## Estratégia Adotada

Primeiramente, leva-se em conta que o algoritmo recebe:

- `cv` = current value = valor atual,
- `cs` = current speed = velocidade atual,
- `ma` = acceleration magnitude = magnitude da aceleração,
- `fv` = final value = valor final,
- `dt` = delta time

e que ele retorna:

- `ncv` = new current value = novo valor atual,
- `ncs` = new current speed = nova velocidade atual.

Além disso, leva-se em conta que:

- se ao desacelerar o valor estacionar antes de alcançar o `fv`, então era melhor acelerar o quanto antes por um tempo para ganhar velocidade até chegar o momento que a desaceleração faz parar no ponto certo
- e caso contrário, mesmo desacelerando pode-se estacionar tanto em `fv` quanto além (cruzar o ponto de chegada e precisar voltar) e em ambos os casos a desaceleração imediata é necessária para que se tenha a inércia no ponto mais próximo de `fv`.

Sendo assim, considera-se que na verdade há dois movimentos retilíneos uniformemente variados distintos, cada um com uma fórmula diferente (uma com aceleração positiva e outra com aceleração negativa). De acordo com a situação, a fórmula correta deve ser selecionada e possivelmente pode-se necessitar do uso de uma fórmula em um trecho do tempo e no restante, a outra.

Para fazer a seleção correta da fórmula, temos que lembrar que o momento de desaceleração ocorre quando os sinais de velocidade e aceleração são opostos (`s*a<0`), portanto:

- `vap(t) = cv + t*( cs + t*ma/2 )` = fórmula de valor em aceleração positiva a partir do momento atual (`vap(0) = cv`),
- `van(t) = cv + t*( cs - t*ma/2 )` = fórmula de valor em aceleração negativa a partir do momento atual (`van(0) = cv`),
- `sap(t) = cs + t*ma` = fórmula de velocidade em aceleração positiva a partir do momento atual (`sap(0) = cs`),
- `san(t) = cs - t*ma` = fórmula de velocidade em aceleração negativa a partir do momento atual (`san(0) = cs`),
- se utiliza quando `cs>=0` em momento de aceleração ou `cs<0` em momento de desaceleração  as fórmulas de função `vap` e função `sap`,
- e se utiliza quando `cs>0` em momento de desaceleração ou `cs<=0` em momento de aceleração as fórmulas de função `van` e função `san`.

Sim, na inércia (`cs=0`) ambos valores de aceleração (positivo ou negativo) indicam aceleração, nunca desaceleração. Isso dá a necessidade de um tratamento de caso de exceção: na inércia, inevitavelmente deve-se acelerar para o lado que leva ao `fv`, ou seja, o sinal da aceleração é `fv-cv`. Se `cv=fv`, então já está parado no valor final e não há o que fazer. Agora saindo dos casos de exceção...

Com isso, podemos saber se ao desacelerar nós cruzamos o valor final ou paramos em cima ou ainda antes, portanto saber se primeiro se acelera para depois desacelerar ou se já começa desacelerando, inverte a velocidade passando a acelerar e depois troca de fórmula para voltar a desacelerar.

Seja qual for o caso, o algoritmo se resume em começar com uma fórmula de aceleração ou desaceleração até contabilizar todo o `dt` ou antes disso alcançar o momento de transição de movimento (ou o próprio `fv`, que matematicamente se vê mais tarde que vale tratar como ponto de transição), aí caso alcance a transição sem esvair o `dt` se troca a fórmula e a aplica até contabilizar todo o `dt` restante ou alcançar o `fv`.

Para saber se antes passa-se o tempo `dt` ou se alcança um momento de transição ou o fim do movimento, é necessário saber qual é o instante em que ocorre a transição ou a finalização e então verificar qual tempo é menor, qual acontece primeiro. As fórmulas dos tempos comparados podem possivelmente serem simplificadas.

> ## Primeira Abstração do Algoritmo

Primeiro precisamos definir se começa com aceleração positiva ou negativa. Os casos de exceção já foram abordados. Em casos gerais, sabe-se que:

- quando `cs>0`, a desaceleração até a inércia ocorre num tempo `cs/ma` com aceleração `-ma` e o ponto onde para é `cv+(cs^2)/(2*ma)`, portanto se `cv+(cs^2)/(2*ma) < fv` (`cs^2 < 2*ma*(fv-cv)`) então é melhor começar acelerando (aceleração positiva)
- e quando `cs<0`, a desaceleração até a inércia ocorre num tempo `-cs/ma` com aceleração `ma` e o ponto onde para é `cv-(cs^2)/(2*ma)`, portanto se `cv-(cs^2)/(2*ma) > fv` (`cs^2 < 2*ma*(cv-fv)`) então é melhor começar acelerando (aceleração negativa).

Em resumo, enxergamos assim as situações.

```
if cs=0:
    if fv=cv:
        MovimentoJáEmEstadoFinal: ncv=cv & ncs=cs
    if fv>cv:
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa
    if fv<cv:
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoNegativaDepoisPositiva
if cs>0:
    if cs^2 < 2*ma*(fv-cv):
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa
    if cs^2 > 2*ma*(fv-cv):
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoNegativaDepoisPositiva
    if cs^2 = 2*ma*(fv-cv):
        MovimentoDeAceleraçãoNegativa
if cs<0:
    if cs^2 < 2*ma*(cv-fv):
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoNegativaDepoisPositiva
    if cs^2 > 2*ma*(cv-fv):
        MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa
    if cs^2 = 2*ma*(cv-fv):
        MovimentoDeAceleraçãoPositiva
```

Assim, resta descobrir em que consiste:

- `MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa`,
- `MovimentosDeAceleraçãoNegativaDepoisPositiva`,
- `MovimentoDeAceleraçãoPositiva` e
- `MovimentoDeAceleraçãoNegativa`.

> ## Cálculo de movimento encerrado ou de aceleração exclusivamente positiva ou exclusivamete negativa

Quando o movimento já está em estado final (executando-se o `MovimentoJáEmEstadoFinal`), isso significa que se está com valor `vf` e em inércia, onde deve permanecer, portanto nem sequer é necessário fazer cálculos, pois somente é necessário retornar os resultados `ncv=fv` e `ncs=0`.

Já quando o cálculo que precisa ser feito é somente de uma fórmula, somente é necessária uma para alcançar a inércia no valor final e para fazer o cálculo do algoritmo somente é necessário verificar se nessa atualização do movimento se chega no estado final (ou seja, calcula-se o tempo para chegar e compara com o `dt`) e, em função disso, definir os valores de `ncv` e `ncs`.

No caso de `MovimentoDeAceleraçãoPositiva`, para saber se chega no fim do movimento (que termina em inércia), deve-se levar em conta que o tempo que leva para chegar lá a partir do instante atual é `-cs/ma`, portanto se chega quando `dt >= -cs/ma`. Se chegar, os resultados são `ncv=cv` e `ncs=cs`, caso contrário são `ncv=vap(dt)` e `ncs=sap(dt)`.

No caso de `MovimentoDeAceleraçãoNegativa`, o tempo que leva para terminar o mobimento a partir do instante atual é `cs/ma`, portanto se chega quando `dt >= cs/ma`. Se chegar, os resultados são `ncv=cv` e `ncs=cs`, caso contrário são `ncv=van(dt)` e `ncs=san(dt)`.

> ## Cálculo de movimento de aceleração positiva seguida de negativa

Quando o movimento a ser calculado é dividido em dois movimentos, um de aceleração positiva e outro de aceleração negativa, isso significa que é necessário trabalhar matematicamente com o instante da transição e o instante de término.

No caso de movimento de aceleração positiva seguida de negativa, ou seja, do cálculo de `MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa`, o instante de transição e o de finalização a partir do momento atual dependem de um resultado de cálculo de raiz quadrada, que é `tmp=sqrt(0.5*cs^2+(fv-cv)*ma)`. O instante de trasição é `tt=(tmp-cs)/ma`. Se `dt <= tt`, então os resultados são `ncv=vap(dt)` e `ncs=sap(dt)`. Caso contrário, precisamos saber o momento que os dois movimentos terminam, que é `ft=(2*tmp-cs)/ma`. Se `dt >= ft`, então os resultados são `ncv=fv` e `ncs=0`, caso contrário são `ncv=cv-dt*(cs+dt*ma/2-tmp-tmp)-(cs-tmp)^2/ma` e `ncs=2*tmp-dt*ma-cs`.

> ## Cálculo de movimento de aceleração negativa seguida de positiva

É similar ao movimento de aceleração positiva seguida de negativa, porém com pequenas mudanças nas fórmulas. No caso do cálculo de `MovimentosDeAceleraçãoPositivaDepoisNegativa`, ele se diferencia do anterior por `tmp=sqrt(0.5*cs^2+(cv-fv)*ma)`, `tt=(tmp+cs)/ma`, se `dt <= tt` então os resultados são `ncv=van(dt)` e `ncs=san(dt)`, caso contrário, `ft=(2*tmp+cs)/ma`, se `dt >= ft` então os resultados são `ncv=fv` e `ncs=0`, caso contrário são `ncv=cv-dt*(cs-dt*ma/2+tmp+tmp)+(cs+tmp)^2/ma` e `ncs=dt*ma-2*tmp-cs`.

> ## Implementação e Teste

O algoritmo foi implementado e testado em linguagem C, formando a função a seguir que salva os resultados em `*newCurrentValue` e `*newCurrentSpeed`. Os cálculos foram bem divididos, partes de resultados salvos em muita variáveis temporárias. Além disso, ao máximo se evitou o cálculo de raiz quadrada, adaptando até as condições.

Na primeira abstração do algoritmo, observamos ao todo nove possibilidades de casos, mas ao implementar e testar percebeu-se que funciona incluir os casos de exceção em outros, definindo assim quatro casos. Para cada um, houve um `goto` para um ponto do programa onde o cálculo ocorre, seja assumindo movimento de aceleração primeiramente positiva e depois negativa (`_ap_an`) ou primeiramente negativa e depois positiva (`_an_ap`).

Logo a seguir está a função de atualização de dados de movimento uniformemente acelerado.

```c
# include <math.h>

void UpdateUam( float currentValue , float currentSpeed , float *newCurrentValue , float *newCurrentSpeed , float deltaTime , float finalValue , float accelerationMagnitude ){
    float das , das2 , s2av , s2avs , da=deltaTime*accelerationMagnitude , s2=currentSpeed*currentSpeed ;
    float a2=accelerationMagnitude+accelerationMagnitude , av=a2*(finalValue-currentValue) ;
    if( currentSpeed < 0 )
        if( s2+av < 0 ) goto _an_ap ;
        else goto _ap_an ;
    else
        if( s2-av < 0 ) goto _ap_an ;
_an_ap:
    das = currentSpeed-da ;
    if( das < 0 ){
        das2 = das*das ;
        s2av = 0.5f*( s2-av ) ;
        if( das2 > s2av ){
            if( das2 >= 4*s2av ){
                *newCurrentValue = finalValue ;
                *newCurrentSpeed = 0 ;
                return ;
            }
            s2av = sqrt( s2av ) ;
            s2avs = s2av+currentSpeed ;
            *newCurrentValue = currentValue-deltaTime*( currentSpeed-0.5f*da+(s2av+s2av) )+s2avs*s2avs/accelerationMagnitude ;
            *newCurrentSpeed = da-(s2av+s2av)-currentSpeed ;
            return ;
        }
    }
    *newCurrentValue = currentValue+deltaTime*( currentSpeed-0.5f*da ) ;
    *newCurrentSpeed = das ;
    return ;
_ap_an:
    das = currentSpeed+da ;
    if( das > 0 ){
        das2 = das*das ;
        s2av = 0.5f*(s2+av) ;
        if( das2 > s2av ){
            if( das2 > 4*s2av ){
                *newCurrentValue = finalValue ;
                *newCurrentSpeed = 0 ;
                return ;
            }
            s2av = sqrt( s2av ) ;
            s2avs = s2av-currentSpeed ;
            *newCurrentValue = currentValue-deltaTime*( currentSpeed+0.5f*da-(s2av+s2av) )-s2avs*s2avs/accelerationMagnitude ;
            *newCurrentSpeed = (s2av+s2av)-da-currentSpeed ;
            return ;
        }
    }
    *newCurrentValue = currentValue+deltaTime*( currentSpeed+0.5f*da ) ;
    *newCurrentSpeed = das ;
}
```

O código foi testado na função `main` onde se inicializa em variável local os dados `iv` (valor inicial), `is` (velocidade inicial), `fv` (valor final) e `a` (magnitude da aceleração). Ele executa para tempos `dt` cada vez maiores (0.2 unidades adicionais por loop) uma atualização com o tal intervalo e também oito atualizações de tempo `dt/8` até que se encontre exatamente os mesmos resultados do ciclo anterior, que é quando estaciona no ponto final.

A seguir, a função `main`.

```c
# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float iv=0 , is=0 , fv=0 , a=1 ;
    float v=iv , s=is , v2=999 , s2=999 , c=0 ; 
    for( float dt=0 ; ( v2*v2+s2*s2>0 )||( c<1.5f ) ; dt+=0.2f , c++ ){
        v2 = v ;  s2 = s ;
        UpdateUam(iv,is,&v,&s,dt,fv,a) ;
        printf(" Time=%4.1f   -->   v=%+7.3f   s=%+7.3f",dt,v,s) ;
        UpdateUam(iv,is,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        UpdateUam(v,s,&v,&s,0.125f*dt,fv,a) ;
        printf("   |-->   v=%+7.3f   s=%+7.3f\n",v,s) ;
        v2 -= v ;  s2 -= s ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Não se encontrou casos em que a função dá resultados inesperados. Além disso, no Maple 2015 se testou a seguinte função que retorna o novo valor atualizado. Neste caso, não se implementou as fórmulas de velocidade, que são simplesmente derivadas das fórmulas de valores.

[image: Função do Maple 2015 que calcula o novo valor após a atualização.]

Utilizando o código a seguir, onde na primeira linha se define os argumentos e na segunda uma lista de magnitudes de acelerações, pode-se testar em vários casos os valores e velocidades visualizando os gráficos, na primeira linha os gráficos de valores (para cada aceleração partindo dos valores iniciais e chegando pouco além dos valores finais do movimento) e na segunda linha, os de velocidade usando diferenças finitas.

[image: ![Código do Maple 2015 que testa a função e exibe gráficos de valores.]

Não foram encontrados casos de resultados inesperados nos gráficos. Para finalizar, a função em C foi convertida para a seguinte em C#.

```cs
public static void UpdateUam( float currentValue , float currentSpeed , out float newCurrentValue , out float newCurrentSpeed , float deltaTime , float finalValue , float accelerationMagnitude ){
    float das , das2 , s2av , s2avs , da=deltaTime*accelerationMagnitude , s2=currentSpeed*currentSpeed ;
    float a2=accelerationMagnitude+accelerationMagnitude , av=a2*(finalValue-currentValue) ;
    if( currentSpeed < 0 )
        if( s2+av < 0 ) goto _an_ap ;
        else goto _ap_an ;
    else
        if( s2-av < 0 ) goto _ap_an ;
_an_ap:
    das = currentSpeed-da ;
    if( das < 0 ){
        das2 = das*das ;
        s2av = 0.5f*( s2-av ) ;
        if( das2 > s2av ){
            if( das2 >= 4*s2av ){
                newCurrentValue = finalValue ;
                newCurrentSpeed = 0 ;
                return ;
            }
            s2av = (float)System.Math.Sqrt( s2av ) ;
            s2avs = s2av+currentSpeed ;
            newCurrentValue = currentValue-deltaTime*( currentSpeed-0.5f*da+(s2av+s2av) )+s2avs*s2avs/accelerationMagnitude ;
            newCurrentSpeed = da-(s2av+s2av)-currentSpeed ;
            return ;
        }
    }
    newCurrentValue = currentValue+deltaTime*( currentSpeed-0.5f*da ) ;
    newCurrentSpeed = das ;
    return ;
_ap_an:
    das = currentSpeed+da ;
    if( das > 0 ){
        das2 = das*das ;
        s2av = 0.5f*(s2+av) ;
        if( das2 > s2av ){
            if( das2 > 4*s2av ){
                newCurrentValue = finalValue ;
                newCurrentSpeed = 0 ;
                return ;
            }
            s2av = (float)System.Math.Sqrt( s2av ) ;
            s2avs = s2av-currentSpeed ;
            newCurrentValue = currentValue-deltaTime*( currentSpeed+0.5f*da-(s2av+s2av) )-s2avs*s2avs/accelerationMagnitude ;
            newCurrentSpeed = (s2av+s2av)-da-currentSpeed ;
            return ;
        }
    }
    newCurrentValue = currentValue+deltaTime*( currentSpeed+0.5f*da ) ;
    newCurrentSpeed = das ;
}
```

Esta função foi utilizada no Unity 2018 para atualizar o `x` da posição de um objeto em relação à posição do mouse, somente quando o botão do mouse é pressionado para que se possa pausar o movimento e testar em mudanças muito bruscas de condições.

```cs
if( Input.GetMouseButton(0) ){
    float x=obj.transform.position.x ;
    UpdateUam( x , s , out x , out s , Time.deltaTime , camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x , 99 ) ;
    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x,0,0) ;
}
```

Não se encontrou anomalias no movimento e foi-se visualmente observada suavidade nas mudanças dos valores. Sendo assim, espero que tudo esteja correto, afinal em todas as versões corrigidas de códigos implementados se viu resultados satisfatórios, ainda que de fato algumas correções tenham sido necessárias.